# Moving Agent A to Nearest Agent B and from their to another nearest Agent B on GIS

Tags: java, anylogic

So I have an agent vehicle and another agent shop of about 10 on GIS. I have another agent warehouse. So I have placed the vehicle at the warehouse and want it to move to the nearest shop and drop goods and from there move to another nearest shop and return to the warehouse after it has reached all shops each only once.

I am new to anylogic and I have run this code
**Agent nearestShop = this.getNearestAgent(main.shops);
moveTo(nearestShop)**

I am stuck and don't know how to move from there using loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use a state chart because you can only start the next route after arriving at the first Shop. This can only be done with the statechart transition set to "Agent arrival".

You can create a statechart "mimicking" a for-loop this way. Best check the example models that use state charts for agent movement to get some inspiration. Do it for 1 shop manually, then for 2 shops, then think how you can combine it into a generic state chart that just keeps on travelling to the next shop until some condition is met (run out of fuel...)

Comment: Thank you. I am finding it difficult to use a state chart... Like I need to remove the current shop of the truck so that it can assess another nearest shop. This is because it is staying in the same shop. I have also checked examples but most are not about Nearest Agent. I will appreciate it if you can assist me with a code or statechart diagram. Thank you @Benjamin